# Are there any flowers that look like snakes?

Tags: botany, species-identification

In [Rio 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2357291/), they showed a flower that almost looks like a snake head (with two fangs and a long tongue).

[image]

Are there any such flowers in real life too?

Comment: Interesting question, but I must say it looks opinion based, as different people may have very different perceptions on the shape of flowers.

Comment: The tongue could be the pistil and the fangs could be the stamens. To find such a flower, you need to search for species with two stamen and a bilateral symmetry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few examples of plants which look like snakes. I'll tell about them one at a time.

- *[Darlingtonia californica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlingtonia_californica)*: or **Cobra Lily**, is a type of pitcher plant which looks much like a snake. It is native to Northern California and Oregon, growing in bogs and seeps with cold running water. See this image:

  [image: cobra lily]
- *[Arisaema triphyllum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arisaema_triphyllum)*: commonly called **Jack-in-the-Pulpit**, it is a type of corm which resembles cobra. It is native to eastern North America, occurring in moist woodlands and thickets from Nova Scotia west to Minnesota, and south to southern Florida and Texas. See this:

  [image: jack in the pulpit]

  A similar and closely related plant, *Arisaema griffithii*, called **Griffith's Cobra Lily**, resembles even more. See this:

  [image: griffiths cobra lily]
- *[Pogonia ophioglossoides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogonia_ophioglossoides)*: also called **Snakemouth Orchid**, whose flowers resemble the face of a snake, pretty much like your image. It is a species of orchid occurring from central Canada to the east-central and eastern United States. See this:

  [image: snakemouth orchid]
- *[Isotria medeoloides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotria_medeoloides)*: named **Little Five Leaves**, its flower also resembles a snake's face. It is a threatened species of terrestrial orchid found in temperate eastern North America. See this:

  [image: little five leaves]

Answer (score 4):

***[Malacothrix coulteri](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjj7In7tpfTAhWDv48KHdN_DjoQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMalacothrix_coulteri&usg=AFQjCNHptaDbWWLMJ8-Rdpx56zIKtaRiyw)*** (Snake's head) looks like the head of a snake.

[image]

It is an annual herb that produces a waxy, upright flowering stem. The inflorescence is an array of flower heads the yellow or white ray florets are about a centimeter long. The bracts are green, often with dark striping or marking.

It is found in sandy and coastal areas, grasslands and deserts.

**For more info:**

See [here](http://www.desertusa.com/flowers/Snakes-Head.html), and if you are interested in it's geographical locations, you can visit [this](http://www.wildflowersearch.com/search?&tsn=38046) page.